# Is there any way to reduce the Tear down time in robot frame work test cases without modifying it

Tags: robotframework

I need some input on below scenario.

We have got a set of around 300 Test cases from another team , During execution 50 % of the time is taken by failed test cases as they keep trying  accessing the APIs during Tear down.

is there any way to get out of a TC or Tear down  immediately when first KW fails by using listener ?
any other solution is also welcome.

Comment: Sorry ! What is KW here ? Just a thought .. if you have a access to the library which they have provided as part of test case just change it to return exit(1) when there is an exception . So when you get exit code 1 make is fail . As I don't know your complete flow ..This is just a thought

Comment: No, that's not possible without modifying. All keywords in a teardown are always executed, and that's not optional. The reason I presume is - teardown are cleanup tasks even if one fails, the system must do best-effort to execute the rest. You might want to play around with test timeouts, they can interrupt a teardown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, There are two Way to overcome the TEARDOWN Time kill in Robot Framework:

1. To use Testcase Timeout option, and use suitable Timeout in which we expect the TC to pass with All Delays expected from Server. If Teardown takes more and more time then, Auto testcase timeout till omit the time kill.
2. Boolean control of the Keywords in Teardown. If we are calling 4 Keywords for Example. Then in the Testcase step generate 4 Booleans which will decide how many Keyword to Run for clean up in Teardown.

For Example :

```
[Setup]     UserProfile Login     ${Admin_Credentials_Track2}
   set test variable  ${BoleanNCA}   ${False}
   set test variable  ${BoleanNCC}   ${False}
   set test variable  ${BooleanNetID}   ${False}
```

Initially Set to False and Set then to TRUE when required Step is Pass in TC.

```
   ${Status}    run keyword and return status   Create NCA with new NetworkID and validate     ${adminUserOauthToken}
   ${BoleanNCA}   set variable if  ${Status}   ${True}   ${BoleanNCA}
```

Now See the TEARDOWN how it will be controlled.

```
   [Teardown]  run keywords   run keyword if  ${BoleanNCA}   NCA Delete        ${adminUserOauthToken}        ${netWrkId}
   ...     AND     run keyword if  ${BoleanNCC}   NCC Delete if Record Exists     ${adminUserOauthToken}        ${netWrkId}
   ...     AND     run keyword if  ${BoleanNCA}   create OCN        ${adminUserOauthToken}        ${entity}       ${OCNLst}
   ...     AND     run keyword if  ${BooleanNetID}  Delete NetWorkId if Exists        ${adminUserOauthToken}        ${netWrkId}
   ...     AND     run keyword if  ${BooleanLogin}  close session
```

Good Luck. I hope it will help.

Comment: That's what i was looking for!!